# JPA CriteriaQuery - access fields from connected table with ManyToOne

Tags: jpa, many-to-one

My situation: A have a datatable called AuditDetail. This table is in ManyToOne connection with another table AuditHead. I display data in Primefaces datatable. My problem is with sorting and filtering. If I want to sort a field witch is in AuditHead table, I got an error: no such field exception.
The related code:

```
public List<AuditDetail> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder     sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<AuditDetail> cq = cb.createQuery(AuditDetail.class);
Root<AuditDetail> from = cq.from(AuditDetail.class);
CriteriaQuery<AuditDetail> select = cq.select(from);
```

It works perfectly with AuditDetail fields, but I don't know how can I reach fields from AuditHead. If I use NamedQueries, I can simply say auditDetail.headId, but how can I get AuditHead fields, when I use CriteriaQuery?
I used NamedQueries before, then this code works perfectly:

```
filterBy="#{log.headId.tableName}" sortBy="#{log.headId.tableName}"
```

I'm here, because I have no idea anymore, I think tried everything. For example:

```
Fetch<AuditDetail, AuditHead> fetch = from.fetch(AuditDetail_.headId, JoinType.LEFT);
```

But I'm absolutely not sure how do I have to do this.

Every help appreciated!
Regards!